# Scripts not rendering in a View MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have code in my _layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and I also have a page called SampleView, where I have the following section:

```
@section Scripts{

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fortable")

}
```

But the problem is, When I load the SampleView, My scripts are not rendering.

I also have tried out the code below in my Section in SampleView

```
@section Scripts{

<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/developer.tableoptions.js")"></script>
}
```

but its also not working!! Any help regarding this issue????

Comment: did you get any error while loading sampleview?

Comment: Did you add the bundle to the `BundleConfig` file? Do you have this line there? `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));`

Comment: No Error while loading the page, but when I go for the ViewSource on Browser, it isnt showing any reference of this Js file

Comment: @chiapa yess!! I have enrolled all the js in BundleConfig

Comment: @ZiyadKashif Have you found a solution to this problem? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have my layout.

First Render your scripts, then The section, like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

@RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution from [this blog](http://blog.madestro.com/post/2013/05/01/Why-are-my-bootstrap-scripts-not-rendering-in-MVC4.aspx).

Basically if your scripts file have `bootstrap.{something}.js`, it would not render the scripts using the `Scripts.Render` method.

The solution is to remove the `.{something}` entirely, in my example it should be `bootstrap.js` only.